# Parsekit, using ParserGenApp and including the created class fails. Calling PKParserFactory and supplying the same grammar works

Tags: parsekit

I have a grammar (included below, but other examples do the same) that I run through ParserGenApp and use the resulting class in an app of mine.  It fails with the following error:

```
  Expected : }
  Line : 3
  Near : start - > 
  Found : start
```

HOWEVER, in the same app, calling

```
PKParser   *parser = [[PKParserFactory factory] parserFromGrammar:bnr assembler:self error:&error];
PKAssembly *result = [parser parse:input error:&error];
```

works just fine.

The grammar is:

```
start              = graph;
graph              = strictOrEmpty graphType id '{' stmtList* '}';
strictOrEmpty      = 'strict' | Empty;
graphType          = 'digraph' | 'graph';
stmtList           = stmt (';' stmtList)* ;
stmt               = nodeDefinition | edgeDefinition;
id                 = Word;

nodeDefinition     = id '[' nodeAttributes ']';
nodeAttributes     = nodeAttribute (',' nodeAttributes)* ;
nodeAttribute      = nodeAttributeKey '=' nodeAttributeValue;
nodeAttributeKey   = Word;
nodeAttributeValue = Word;

edgeDefinition     = id edgeLinkSymbol id;
edgeLinkSymbol     = '->';
```

Comment: Developer of ParseKit here. Please share the example input you are using that is producing this error message. Without the example input, it's very difficult to say what the issue is.

Comment: digraph G {

 start -> a0;
 start -> b0;
 a1 -> b3;
 b2 -> a3;
 a3 -> a0;
 a3 -> end;
 b3 -> end;

 start [shape=Mdiamond];
 end [shape=Msquare, color=red];

}